# Printing out even and odd numbers using thread in C

Tags: c, pthreads, computer-science

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

pthread_mutex_t mutex = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
void* thread_even(void* arg);
void* thread_odd(void* arg);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    pthread_t tid[2];

    pthread_create(&tid[0], 0, &thread_even, 0);
    pthread_create(&tid[1], 0, &thread_odd, 0);

    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);

    return 0;
}

void* thread_even(void* arg) {
    int* thread_id = (int*)arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    for(int i = 1; i <= *thread_id; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 != 0)
        {
            printf("Thread 1: %d", i);
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}

void* thread_odd(void* arg) {
    int* thread_id = (int*)arg;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);

    for(int i = 1; i <= *thread_id; i++)
    {
        if(i%2 == 0)
        {
            printf("Thread 2: %d", i);
        }
    }

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);

    return NULL;
}
```

The above is the code I am working on but I get a segment fault error... What I want to achieve is, for example,

when I compile it and run with an argument 8 (./number 8)

it should print out

thread 1: 1

thread 2: 2

thread 1: 3

... etc till the number, 8.

in which thread 1s should represent the even numbers and the thread 2s stand for the odd numbers.

Please help... I want to develop my knowledge about C but have no one to ask..
Thanks.

Comment: `int* thread_id = (int*)arg;` - um... you passed `NULL` as the argument to `pthread_create` for what is `arg` here. Not surprisingly, `i <= *thread_id` dereferences `NULL`, and thusly invokes *undefined behavior*.

Comment: then what should I pass as the argument to make the program successful? Thanks!

Comment: @seung, see my answer. Also the locking you have done is probably more coarse than you are looking for. As you have it right now, effectively one thread will complete, and then the other will run.

Comment: @EvanTeran Im really sorry but I really want to know how to do it in my way... can I know what argument should I pass to even and odd function?

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this'run thread code alternately' question.  They all seem to try to use a mutex when two semaphores are the sane solution, (if any such requirement is sane - it's obviously an exercise/homework).  Why do they all try to use the wrong synchro?  Is it because 'mutex' is a cooler name, or requires less typing?

Comment: @seung, LOOK at my answer, i put an example of that in there...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are passing `0` AKA `NULL` to the last parameter of `pthread_create`, and then doing the following:

```
int* thread_id = (int*)arg;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
for(int i = 1; i <= *thread_id; i++)
```

So, `thread_id` will certainly be `NULL`, referencing it will be a SEGFAULT.

If you want to pass an upper bound for each thread to run to, do you can do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    pthread_t tid[2];
    int *ids = malloc(2 * sizeof(int));
    ids[0] = 10; /* upper bound for thread 1 */
    ids[1] = 10; /* upper bound for thread 2 */

    pthread_create(&tid[0], 0, &thread_even, &ids[0]);
    pthread_create(&tid[1], 0, &thread_odd, &ids[1]);

    pthread_join(tid[0], NULL);
    pthread_join(tid[1], NULL);

    free(ids);
    return 0;
}
```

There are ways to do this without resorting to heap allocation, but this is the most straight forward.

Comment: thank you so much! but it prints out thread 1 thread 1 and thread 2 thread2 like this. Is there any way to print them out alternatively?

Comment: As my comment mentioned, your mutexes as you've written, will do all of one thread. How to solve that problem is a separate question.